# Criar tempo de entrega por grupo de CEP

Tags: php, javascript, formulário

Tenho um formulário que calcula o custo da entrega por grupo de CEP, o que eu preciso agora é que cada grupo acrescente um tempo de entrega.
Exemplo: O grupo de CEP que cobra R$ 4,30 terá o tempo de entrega em 50 minutos, já o grupo de CEP que cobra R$ 6,50 terá o tempo de entrega em 120 minutos...

Segue o código do arquivo form.js onde tem esse calculo:

```
var str = "";
var id = "";
var sub = 0.00;
var taxa = 0;
var taxadeentrega = total - taxa;
var total = 0.00;
var qcount = 0;
var scount = 0;
var opc = 0;
var options = "";
for (i=1; i<21; i++){
    options += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "div div select" ).html(options); 
    $( "div div :text" ).attr("value","1");
    $( "#emporio" ).css("display","block");
    $( "#mudaopcao" ).click(function() {
      location.reload(true);
    });
    function alerta(txt){
        $( "div#alerta" ).html( txt ).show( 0 ).delay( 2500 ).fadeOut( 500 );
    }
function atencao(txt){
        $( "div#atencao" ).html( txt ).show( 0 ).delay( 2500 ).fadeOut( 500 );
    }
    function mens(){
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getDate() + "|" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "|" + d.getFullYear() + " - " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();

        $( "div#quentes :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
              str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text();
              if (opc == 4){
                  var sel = $(this).parent().children("span").children("select").val();
                  str = str + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
              }
              str = str + "<br>";
        })
        $('input[name=quentes]').val(str);
        str = "";



        $( "div#embalagem :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
              str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
        })
        $('input[name=embalagem]').val(str);
        str = "";



        $( "div#molhos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
              str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text();
              if (opc == 4){
                  var sel = $(this).parent().children("span").children("select").val();
                  str = str + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
              }
              str = str + "<br>";
        })
        $('input[name=molhos]').val(str);
        str = "";



        $( "div#saladas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
              str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text();
              if (opc == 4){
                  var sel = $(this).parent().children("span").children("select").val();
                  str = str + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
              }
              str = str + "<br>";
        })
        $('input[name=saladas]').val(str);
        str = "";

        $( "div#sobremesas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
              str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
        })
        $('input[name=sobremesas]').val(str);
        str = "";

        $( "div#sucos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
              var val = $(this).parent().children("input:radio:checked").val();
              str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + " - " + $(this).parent().children("input:radio:checked").attr("l") + ": R$ " + val.replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (val * sel).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
        })
        $('input[name=sucos]').val(str);
        str = "";

        $( "div#bebidas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
              str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
        })
        $('input[name=bebidas]').val(str);
        str = "";

        $( "div#sopas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
              str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
        })
        $('input[name=sopas]').val(str);
        str = "";

        $( "div#emporio :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
              var sel = $(this).parent().children("select").val();
              str = str + $(this).parent().children("strong").text() + ": R$ " + $(this).val().replace(".", ",") + " x " + sel + " = R$ " + (($(this).val() * sel).toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") + "<br>";
        })
        $('input[name=emporio]').val(str);
        str = "";

        str = String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
        $('input[name=mtotal]').val(str);
        str = "";

        str = String(+ taxa.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",");
        $('input[name=taxadeentrega]').val(str);
        str = "";


        if(opc==1){
            $('input[name=op]').val("3 Quentes e 3 Saladas");
        }else if(opc==2){
            $('input[name=op]').val("4 Quentes e 4 Saladas");
        }else if(opc==3){
            $('input[name=op]').val("5 Quentes e 5 Saladas");
        }else{
            $('input[name=op]').val("");
        }

        if(opc==0){
            $('input[name=nop]').val("");       
        } else {
            str = "<strong>Opção " + opc + ": </strong>";
            $('input[name=nop]').val(str);
            str = "";
        }

        $('input[name=data]').val(n);
    }

      $("div#quentes :checkbox").click(function(){
          if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
              qcount++;
              if (opc == 1){
                  if (qcount == 4){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                      atencao("Você só pode escolher 3 pratos quentes, para mais escolha outra opção");
                      qcount = 3;
                  }
                  if (qcount == 1){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 pratos quentes");

                  }
                  if (qcount == 2){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 prato quente");

                  }
              } else if (opc == 2){
                  if (qcount == 5){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                      atencao("Você só pode escolher 4 pratos quentes, para mais escolha outra opção");
                      qcount = 4;
                  }
                   if (qcount == 1){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 pratos quentes");

                  }
                  if (qcount == 2){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 pratos quentes");

                  }
                   if (qcount == 3){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 prato quente");

                  }
              } else if (opc == 3){
                  if (qcount == 6){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                      atencao("Você só pode escolher 5 pratos quentes, para mais escolha outra opção");
                      qcount = 5;
                  }
                    if (qcount == 1){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 4 pratos quentes");

                  }
                  if (qcount == 2){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 pratos quentes");

                  }
                   if (qcount == 3){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 pratos quentes");

                  }
                   if (qcount == 4){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 prato quente");

                  }
              }
          } else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
              qcount--;
          }
      }) 





      $("div#saladas :checkbox").click(function(){
          if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
              scount++;
              if (opc == 1){
                  if (scount == 4){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                      atencao("Você só pode escolher 3 saladas, para mais escolha outra opção");
                      scount = 3;
                  }
                  if (scount == 1){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 saladas");
                  }
                  if (scount == 2){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 salada");
                  }

              } else if (opc == 2){
                  if (scount == 5){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                      atencao("Você só pode escolher 4 saladas, para mais escolha outra opção");
                      scount = 4;
                  }
                   if (scount == 1){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 saladas");
                  }
                  if (scount == 2){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 saladas");
                  }
                  if (scount == 3){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 salada");
                  }

              } else if (opc == 3){
                  if (scount == 6){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", false );
                      atencao("Você só pode escolher 5 saladas, para mais escolha outra opção");
                      scount = 5;
                  }
                  if (scount == 1){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 4 saladas");
                  }
                  if (scount == 2){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 3 saladas");
                  }
                  if (scount == 3){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 2 saladas");
                  }
                  if (scount == 4){
                      $( this ).prop( "checked", true );
                      alerta("Você ainda pode escolher 1 salada");
                  }
              }
          } else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
              scount--;
          }
      })

      $( ":input" ).click(function() {
      total = 0;
      sub = 0;

      if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).length > 0) {
        $( "#mudaopcao, #titulo2, div#quentes :checkbox, div#saladas :checkbox" ).css("display","inline-block");
        sub += $( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).val() * 1;
        if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 1){
            opc = 1;
            $( "#op2,#op3,#op4,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
        } else if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 2){
            opc = 2;
            $( "#op1,#op3,#op4,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
        } else if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 3){
            opc = 3;
            $( "#op1,#op2,#op4,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
        } else if ($( "div#opcoes input:radio:checked" ).attr("op") == 4){
            opc = 4;
            $( "#op1,#op2,#op3,div#quentes span" ).css("display","none");
            $("div#quentes span, div#saladas span").css("display","inline-block");

            $( "div#quentes :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
                sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().find("select").val();
            }) //each quentes


            $( "div#saladas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
                sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().find("select").val();
            }) //each saladas
        }
      }


        $( "div#embalagem :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
        }) //each embalagem



       $( "div#molhos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function(i) {
        if (i > 0) {
          sub += $( this ).val() * 1;
        }
    }); // each molhos


        $( "div#sobremesas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
        }) //each sobremesas


        $( "div#sucos :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).parent().children( ":radio:checked" ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
        }) //each sucos


        $( "div#bebidas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
        }) //each bebidas

        $( "div#sopas :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
        }) //each sopas

        $( "div#emporio :checkbox:checked" ).each(function() {
            sub += $( this ).val() * $( this ).parent().children( "select" ).val();
        }) //each emporio

        total += sub;


        //aqui eu pego o cep
var cep = document.getElementById("cep").value;

//verifica se deve incrementar ou não
if(cep == "20040-010" || cep == "22750-009" || cep == "20071-002" || cep == "20090-910" || cep == "20210-010" || cep == "20080-102" || cep == "20230-130" || cep == "20081-250" || cep == "20090-030" || cep == "20090-030" || cep == "20211-340" || cep == "20211-351" || cep == "20221-240" || cep == "20221-250" || cep == "20230-010" || cep == "20230-011" || cep == "20230-025" || cep == "20230-150" || cep == "20230-160" || cep == "20230-240" || cep == "20231-016" || cep == "20231-030" || cep == "20231-031" || cep == "20231-050" || cep == "20211-005" || cep == "20231-085" || cep == "20230-014" || cep == "20231-004" || cep == "20021-180" || cep == "20240-180" || cep == "20240-051" || cep == "20211-010" || cep == "20230-170" || cep == "20230-024" || cep == "20240-050" || cep == "20230-050" || cep == "20231-006" || cep == "20090-010" || cep == "20230-901" || cep == "20040-051" || cep == "20241-080" || cep == "20221-901" || cep == "20051-011" || cep == "20021-190" || cep == "20240-200" || cep == "20230-170" || cep == "20231-015" || cep == "20211-350" || cep == "20231-020" || cep == "20061-030" || cep == "20050-092" || cep == "20240-050" || cep == "20230-070" || cep == "20230-015" || cep == "20021-350" || cep == "20230-070"){

        //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 4 no valor final
    taxa = 4.30;


        //verifica se deve incrementar ou não
}if(cep == "22221-010" || cep == "22221-011" || cep == "22210-906" || cep == "22250-060" || cep == "22250-020" || cep == "22250-902" || cep == "22250-903" || cep == "22250-030" || cep == "22230-020" || cep == "22210-030" || cep == "22210-065" || cep == "22210-901" || cep == "22210-903" || cep == "22210-904" || cep == "22210-902" || cep == "22210-060" || cep == "22210-905" || cep == "22250-110" || cep == "22220-080" || cep == "22220-900" || cep == "22230-075" || cep == "22220-030" || cep == "22231-140" || cep == "22210-050" || cep == "22230-010" || cep == "22250-130" || cep == "22220-050" || cep == "22220-040" || cep == "22230-040" || cep == "22210-040" || cep == "22250-100" || cep == "22250-120" || cep == "22220-060" || cep == "22230-060" || cep == "22230-061" || cep == "22230-902" || cep == "22230-903" || cep == "22230-901" || cep == "22230-030" || cep == "22231-150" || cep == "22210-085" || cep == "22210-080" || cep == "22230-080" || cep == "22250-090" || cep == "22250-070" || cep == "22231-130" || cep == "22250-080" || cep == "22230-000" || cep == "22230-001" || cep == "22230-900" || cep == "22221-000" || cep == "22210-070" || cep == "22230-070" || cep == "22230-050" || cep == "22231-230" || cep == "22240-180" || cep == "22240-090" || cep == "22240-120" || cep == "22240-030" || cep == "22231-210" || cep == "22245-130" || cep == "22240-160" || cep == "22231-170" || cep == "22231-900" || cep == "22240-130" || cep == "22241-020" || cep == "22240-080" || cep == "22240-170" || cep == "22231-220" || cep == "22245-020" || cep == "22245-070" || cep == "22221-110" || cep == "22245-000" || cep == "22231-110" || cep == "22245-030" || cep == "22245-060" || cep == "22240-000" || cep == "22240-003" || cep == "22240-004" || cep == "22240-006" || cep == "22240-005" || cep == "22240-900" || cep == "22221-120" || cep == "22221-130" || cep == "22240-040" || cep == "22231-160" || cep == "22240-020" || cep == "22221-070" || cep == "22245-110" || cep == "22245-120" || cep == "22221-100" || cep == "22231-120" || cep == "22245-140" || cep == "22240-100" || cep == "22231-070" || cep == "22245-050" || cep == "22241-000" || cep == "22241-970" || cep == "22231-100" || cep == "22221-080" || cep == "22231-200" || cep == "22245-010" || cep == "22221-090" || cep == "22221-140" || cep == "22231-090" || cep == "22231-901" || cep == "22240-150" || cep == "22231-080" || cep == "22245-150" || cep == "22245-040" || cep == "22245-100" || cep == "22240-060" || cep == "22240-140" || cep == "22241-010" || cep == "22240-110" || cep == "22231-180" || cep == "22240-070" || cep == "22245-080" || cep == "22245-090" || cep == "22221-150" || cep == "22240-010" || cep == "20211-110" || cep == "22220-020" || cep == "22231-190"){

        //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 5.5 no valor final
    taxa = 6.50;


    //verifica se deve incrementar ou não
}if(cep == "20241-220" || cep == "22210-015" || cep == "22220-000" || cep == "20241-160" || cep == "20021-040" || cep == "20241-150" || cep == "22210-010" || cep == "22211-230" || cep == "22220-000" || cep == "22220-070" || cep == "22221-060" || cep == "22211-200" || cep == "22221-020" || cep == "20241-180" || cep == "20240-200"){

        //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 5.5 no valor final
    taxa = 6.0;


}if(cep == "20050-091" || cep == "20060-050" || cep == "20071-000" || cep == "20080-003" || cep == "20081-000" || cep == "20081-050" || cep == "20090-000" || cep == "20090-003" || cep == "20231-092" || cep == "24938-600" || cep == "20051-002" || cep == "20090-050" || cep == "20231-046" || cep == "20231-047" || cep == "20231-048" || cep == "20060-070" || cep == "20231-094" || cep == "20090-001" || cep == "20231-093" || cep == "20051-011" || cep == "20060-010" || cep == "20050-002"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 3.5 no valor final
    taxa = 3.8;


    }if(cep == "20090-003" || cep == "20071-001" || cep == "20221-901"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 4.8 no valor final
    taxa = 4.8;


}if(cep == "20031-170" || cep == "20040-004" || cep == "20040-902" | cep == "20021-360" || cep == "20040-020" || cep == "20040-908" || cep == "20071-000" || cep == "20230-070" || cep == "20071-004" || cep == "20040-009" || cep == "20230-060"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 3 no valor final
    taxa = 3.30;

}if(cep == "20010-010" || cep == "20020-906" || cep == "20031-908" || cep == "20031-917" || cep == "20040-001" || cep == "20040-006" || cep == "20050-090" || cep == "20070-022" || cep == "20031-909" || cep == "20031-904" || cep == "20021-390" || cep == "20031-919" || cep == "20031-912" || cep == "20031-905" || cep == "20050-060" || cep == "20031-901" || cep == "20070-021" || cep == "20031-924" || cep == "20051-040" || cep == "20031-901" || cep == "20003-191" || cep == "20241-110" || cep == "20031-900" || cep == "20050-030"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 2.5 no valor final
    taxa = 2.80;


}if(cep == "20010-020" || cep == "20011-020" || cep == "20011-030" || cep == "20011-040" || cep == "20011-901" || cep == "20020-000" || cep == "20010-170" || cep == "20011-000" || cep == "20021-260" || cep == "20031-040" || cep == "20031-050" || cep == "20031-130" || cep == "20031-204" || cep == "20021-245" || cep == "20040-002" || cep == "21335-253" || cep == "20040-031" || cep == "20030-041" || cep == "20040-000" || cep == "20004-002" || cep == "20040-003" || cep == "20040-007" || cep == "20030-042" || cep == "20011-010"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 1.7 no valor final
    taxa = 2.00;


}if(cep == "20010-090" || cep == "20020-100" || cep == "20021-130" || cep == "20021-315" || cep == "20030-001" || cep == "20031-000" || cep == "20031-003" || cep == "20031-010" || cep == "20031-050" || cep == "20031-141" || cep == "20031-143" || cep == "20031-005" || cep == "20031-001" || cep == "20020-903" || cep == "20031-144" || cep == "20030-080" || cep == "20031-142" || cep == "20031-120" || cep == "20031-007" || cep == "20010-009" || cep == "20031-913" || cep == "20021-370" || cep == "20200-100" || cep == "20030-901" || cep == "20030-021" || cep == "20210-030" || cep == "24220-280"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 1.2 no valor final
    taxa = 1.50;


}if(cep == "20020-010"|| cep == "22050-032" || cep == "20020-040" || cep == "20020-080" || cep == "20021-060" || cep == "20021-120" || cep == "20021-900" || cep == "20021-903" || cep == "20030-002" || cep == "20030-015" || cep == "20030-013" || cep == "20030-020" || cep == "20030-021" || cep == "20030-060" || cep == "20030-070" || cep == "20030-120" || cep == "20002-080" || cep == "20002-008" || cep == "20003-021" || cep == "20030-905" || cep == "24220-031" || cep == "20002-010" || cep == "20030-015"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 0.7 no valor final
    taxa = 1.00; 

}

total += taxa;      

if(taxa != 0){

//caso a taxa seja diferente de 0, mostra ao usuário
    document.getElementById("idTaxa").innerHTML = "Custo adicional: R$ " + taxa;
}

        $( "div#total" ).html( "Valor total da sua<br>encomenda: R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") );
        $( "div#total" ).css("display", "block");
        $( "#total2" ).html( "R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") );      
      }) //click
      $( "#total2" ).html( "R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ",") );      


      $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
         if (opc == 4 && (qcount + scount)<6){
            event.preventDefault();
            alerta("Você deve escolher, no mínimo, 6 itens, entre os pratos quentes e saladas");
            return false;
        } else if (total < 22.90){
            event.preventDefault();
            alerta("O valor mínimo do pedido é R$ 22,90");
            return false;
        } else if ($("#nome").val()=="" || $("#endereco").val()=="" || $("#email").val()=="" || $("#cep").val()=="" || $("#telefone").val()==""){
            event.preventDefault();
            alerta("Todos os campos de informação são obrigatórios");
            return false;
        }
        mens();
      }); //form

}); // doc ready
```

Segue link do formulário:

[Formulário online](https://jsfiddle.net/pgor1fqk/)

Answer (score 0):

Eu sugiro que você use uma abordagem diferente para sua solução. Podemos usar um mapa com todos esses ceps e os valores que você vai precisar extrair. Isso vai evitar o excesso de `if` no seu código e facilitar alterações futuras.

**IMPORTANTE**: Nos códigos abaixo, lembre-se que o uso das reticências (...) é apenas pra encurtar. Substitua pelo resto dos ceps necessários.

Exemplo:

```
var cepMap = {
    "group1": {
        "ceps": ["20040-010", "22750-009", "20071-002", ...],
        "taxa": 4.30,
        "tempoEntrega": 50
    },
    "group2": {
        "ceps": ["20241-220", "22210-015", "22220-000", ...],
        "taxa": 6.00,
        "tempoEntrega": 120
    },
    ...
};
```

Desse jeito, você pode criar uma função que retorne exatamente o que você quer baseado no cep, por exemplo. Veja:

```
function retornaValor(cep, valorEsperado) {
    for (var i in cepMap){
        var group = cepMap[i],
            ceps = group.ceps;

        if (ceps.indexOf(cep) > -1) {
             return group[valorEsperado];
        };
    };
};
```

E para executar:

```
var taxa = retornaValor("20040-010", "taxa"); // taxa será igual 4.3
var tempo = retornaValor("20241-220", "tempoEntrega"); // tempo será igual 120
```

Comment: Obrigado Brunno Vianna! Eu sou leigo, não sei como colocar esses últimos códigos. Entendi a sua dinâmica, mas não sei como colocar no meu código atual. Pode me ajudar? Coloquei um link do formulário no post. A única diferença desse formulário para o real é que ele não recebe a informação do CEP (isso é carregado quando o usuário loga no formulário), mas repare que lá embaixo tem o campo que carregar as informações do Total do seu pedido e Taxa de Entrega. O Tempo de Entrega eu acabei de criar para quando o sistema funcionar, ele mostra nesse campo essa informação.

Comment: Logo depois da função que eu criei (seguindo o formulário no fiddler que você postou):

    taxa = retornaValor(cep, "taxadeentrega");
    total += taxa;

Exatamente como está colocado ali na resposta.

Comment: E aí pode fazer o mesmo para qualquer outro valor que você quiser acrescentar na aplicação. Basta inserir mais uma propriedade no objeto cepMap e chamar a função retornaValor, passando o cep como primeiro argumento e o nome da propriedade como segundo.